# How to implement a vertical scroll bar for openTK gameWindow

Tags: c#, 3d, opentk

I am developing a 2d windows application using openTK and c#.
i am using gamewindow class.

```
class myWindow : GameWindow
{
}
```

is there any way to implement a vertical scroll bar for this window??
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your-very-own `Scrollbar` widget. Draw it in 2D using OpenGL:

```
DrawVerticalScrollBar(scrollbar_x, scrollbar_y, 
   scrollbar_width, scrollbar_height, 
   vertical_scroll, min_value, max_value); //pseudocode
```

Then later draw the contents of the "scroll-bar" view:

```
GL.Enable(EnableCap.ScissorTest);
GL.Scissor(view_start_x, view_start_y, view_end_x, view_end_y);

// Assume matrix mode is modelview
GL.PushMatrix();
GL.Translate(0, -vertical_scroll, 0);
      // Draw the graphics affected by scrollbar
GL.PopMatrix();

GL.Disable(EnableCap.ScissorTest);

// Draw rest of the 2d graphics
```

If you don't want to clip contents of the view, you can remove the `ScissorTest` and `GL.Scissor`